# Calling Sort-Object without pipe in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, pipe

I'm new to PowerShell and am just trying to figure out how it works exactly.

So, how can I write this code:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\ | Sort-Object Length
```

as multi lined code? I tried this:

```
$child_items = Get-ChildItem C:\
Sort-Object $child_items Length
```

but it didn't work. I'm getting:

```
Sort-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Length'.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the other answers are the right way to pass value using named parameter remember what `get-help Sort-Object` say:

```
When you use the InputObject parameter to submit a collection of items, 
Sort-Object receives one object that represents the collection. 
Because one object cannot be sorted, Sort-Object returns the entire collection unchanged.
```

You'll find that no sort operation will be done passing $child_items to `-inputobject`.

You always need to pass value with a pipe to `-inputobject`

Comment: ... and if you do not like it, you can vote up this connect item: http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/568524/sort-object-does-not-sort-items-in-collections-passed-in-through-the-inputobject-parameter

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the -InputObject parameter. Without it, $child_items will bind to the first positional parameter, which is 'Property'

```
Sort-Object -InputObject $child_items Length
```

UPDATE

I'm not removing my answer cause there are comments attached to it. I was wrong, the results from Get-ChildItem are sorted by default and I concluded that passing the array to InputObject does the job. Clearly I was wrong, check @C.B answer.

Comment: Although the script runs with this, the objects are no longer sorted. Why's that?

Comment: @SebastianKrysmanski What are you doing with the reult of `Sort-Object`? Remember it does not sort in place.

Comment: I just want to write its result to the console (so that it matches the output of the piped alternative).

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\ | 
Sort-Object Length
```

Or for you example this would work too;

```
$child_items = Get-ChildItem C:\
$child_items | Sort-Object Length
```

You can also use the back tick as a line continuation character .

Comment: I would say he should use the backtick ` , because some cmdlets won't run without it, at least not consistently and it makes it more readable.